# Post processing slowness on dev org

Tags: rest-api, performance, slowness

We have build custom API on slaesforce. This API is call from C# multilayered application. it stats 1000 threads and hit the custom api almost at same time. Salesforce receive and process all this request as we can see the result in custom objects and debug logs.

After processing all request salesforce org becomes super slow and does not allow any user to navigate thru menu and list views.

After some time it becomes normal and function just fine.

Does any one know why its behaving like this. If there is issue in Apex code then it should slow it down and throw any of the limit exception.

Why it is slowing down after processing the requests?

Debug log is saying each request is processed in < 200 ms which is good enough for us.